# How to build desktop App using electron

Tags: node.js, angular, electron

I have a website which I build using Angular as frontend and NodeJs as my backend with mysql as the database. I want to create same version of the website as desktop application using ELECTRON, Am new to electron, Can someone guild me on how to build this desktop app. also do not forget my database which in mysql.

With Kind Regards,

Comment: This would be a good place to start: https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/

Comment: Use nw.js It is better

Comment: Can I build the application alongside with mysql database? @Silve2611 thank you.

Comment: https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-your-first-nw-js-desktop-application-in-less-than-5-minutes

Comment: https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Getting%20Started/

Comment: Thank you for fast respond @Silve2611

Comment: Precise your question if you don't get along with the install and i will help you.

Comment: Alright thank you. Let me try it out @Silve2611

Comment: @Silve2611 what is better in nw.js? I think electron is better since it is more widly known has the better documentation and a more extensive API. Especially if you look on the multi-context in chrome. And also in electrons Chrome is unpatched, while nw.js added hacks.

Comment: nw.js has been there longer and offers more. source code protection for example. If you want to build professional apps a must have

Comment: V8 snapshots do work in electron too. Also no you don't do your business logic in javascript in professional apps especially since the V8 snapshots are not protecting your Javascript code from being read. You would use bindings to a native language like C++, C, Rust, Go and electron handles the frontend. Overall your arguments are pretty weak, don't take this wrong but one-liner opinions are the weakest arguments there is. Please don't distribute them it only damages the mindset of other with wrong information.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to know what kind of web application you have and what you're trying to aim with the desktop application.

One solution could be to just embed your web page in the desktop application, inside a [webview](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/webview-tag/).